# Gaps appear inside the sprites from SWF

Tags: flash, sprite, haxe, openfl, adobe-animate

I'm using Adobe Animate to draw assets for my game, however, small gaps appear between different parts of the sprite. How to fix it?

Comparison between how it appears in Adobe Animate and how it appears in game:

[image: expected]
[image: actual]

[image: expected]
[image: actual]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(just to be clear, I am no expert just letting you know my thoughts and experience)

This is an issue I have been fighting myself; I believe the issue resides in how anti-aliasing is done in Animate/Flash vs OpenFL.  Disabling anti-aliasing in OpenFL will get rid of the small gaps but the art will look poor. i believe Flash renders everything on a layer first and then use a a 4x4 pixel grid for anti-aliasing that layer before continuing, while OpenFL on the other hand use anti-aliasing for every drawn shape and so the gaps you see is a mix of your objects color and its surroundings (usually its the alpha channel)

[image: Anti-aliasing]

I have tried to solve this with various tricks for OpenFLs Cairo targets with some success but the issue will still be present for all non-Cairo targets. For instance HTML5.

[image: Image of render results for experimental OpenFL branch]

[Experimental OpenFL branch](https://github.com/m0rkeulv/openfl/tree/experiments/renderQuality)

My best advice when it comes to get rid of these artifacts/gaps is to either separate  the problem areas into different layers or to use export as bitmap if using layers is too inconvenient.

Btw, there is both an official forum and Discord channel for OpenFL you might get some better answers/suggestions there.